# How do I add donation functionality to a non-profit website?

Tags: javascript, paypal, transactions, credit-card, donations

I am developing a website for an NGO from scratch.

How do I add functionality that will enable users to make donations via PayPal/Credit card?

Comment: Please provide anything you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a donation button from PayPal very easily.

1. Register your NGO with PayPal and verify your account.
2. Login and follow the [Steps](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/donate-step-1/)
3. Copy the button code and Past it in your site.

Comment: Doesnt work for Serbia.